# Remove first line in 'stdout_lines'

Tags: automation, ansible, cisco-ios

I'm just a beginner and write some small playbook.

For now I get some little error.

```yaml
- name: Facts
  ios_command:
    commands: show interface status
  register: ios_comm_result
```

In this playbook, for beginner I get the list of interfaces and then in next task I get list with first position including column name.

```yaml
- name: get a list of ports to modify
  set_fact:
    newlist: "{{ (newlist | default([])) + [item.split()[0]] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ios_comm_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Output:

```
'Port'
'fa0/1'
'gi0/2'
....
 etc
```

How can I delete first line? Or where can I read about this?

Comment: try `ios_comm_result.stdout_lines[1:]`  ---not tested.

Comment: What @P.... said, or that's a fine use case for [`| reject("match", "^Port") | list`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#reject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement and the given comments about [Accessing list elements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) with [Slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/) (`[1:]`) and [Jinja Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#builtin-filters) (`| reject()`) I've setup an short test

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    STDOUT_LINES: ['Port', 'fa0/1', 'gi0/2', 'etc/3']

  tasks:

  # Slice notation

  - name: Show 'stdout_lines' from the 2nd line to the end
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ STDOUT_LINES[1:] }}"

  # Jinja2 filter

  - name: Show 'stdout_lines' and drop any lines which match
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ STDOUT_LINES | reject('match', '^Port') | list }}"

  # Conditionals

  - name: Show 'stdout_lines' but not the first one
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: ansible_loop.index != 1
    loop: "{{ STDOUT_LINES }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

with some value added about [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) and [using conditionals in loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#using-conditionals-in-loops).

All three options show the expected result.